Reusable React hook vs complex javascript response structure
I'm writing a web application using React.
In my code I have plenty different calls to the database.
All of this calls look very similar.
The only difference are table names and parameters and therefore I have a lot of functions that fetch the data.
For this reason I figured that I will write a generic hook that will take care of all my API calls.
The hook looks like this:
"use client"

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useAWSGenericRequest(fetch_callback) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState({
      status: "pending",
      value: []
    });


    useEffect(() => {
      fetch_callback().then(function(request) {
        request.on("success", function(response){
          setValue(function() {
            return {
              status: "success",
              value: response}
          });
        });
        request.send();
      });
      }, []);
    return { value: value, setValue: setValue };
}

Then in the code I use it like this:
import { FetchUsers } from '@/app/lib/fetch-users.js';
import { useAWSGenericRequest } from '@/app/ui/hooks/use-aws-generic-request.js'
.
.
.
export default function ListOfUsers(props) {
    const users = useAWSGenericRequest(FetchUsers);
.
.
.
    return (users.value.value.data.Users.map(function(user, i) 
        => return (<div key={i}>{user.email}</div>)));

}


This code is simplified but it portrays the problem that I have.
The nested structure of my API response "users.value.value.data.Users" causes my user interface to be no longer responsive once the "users.value.value.data.Users" changes.
I read on the internet that react will not react on the nested array changes.
One solution would be to modify the generic hook that I mentioned earlier and make it look like this:
"use client"

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useAWSGenericRequest(fetch_callback) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
      fetch_callback().then(function(request) {
        request.on("success", function(response){
          setValue(function() {
            return response.value.data.Users);
        });
        request.send();
      });
      }, []);
    return [value, setValue];
}

Then in the code I could use it like this:
import { FetchUsers } from '@/app/lib/fetch-users.js';
import { useAWSGenericRequest } from '@/app/ui/hooks/use-aws-generic-request.js'
.
.
.
export default function ListOfUsers(props) {
    const [users, setUsers] = useAWSGenericRequest(FetchUsers);
.
.
.
    return (users.map(function(user, i) 
        => return (<div key={i}>{user.email}</div>)));

}


In this case React does react and reloads the user interface every time I change the "users" array.
The problem obviously is that If I wanted to fetch some other value then I would need to copy my hook and replace the dotted path to get the resource I'm interested in like in this example response.value.some.other.value:
"use client"

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useAWSGenericRequest(fetch_callback) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
      fetch_callback().then(function(request) {
        request.on("success", function(response){
          setValue(function() {
            return response.value.some.other.value);
        });
        request.send();
      });
      }, []);
    return [value, setValue];
}

I feel like I'm missing some very simple trick/pattern but I just don't know what it is.
Is there a way to create a generic hook like I'm trying to or do I need to accept the fact that I have create new hook for each new API call?
Best Regards

I your example, as far as I can see, users.value.value.data.Users only changes if users also changes, so React should re-render anyway. Are you trying to modify users.value.value.data.Users somewhere else ?

@kca yes I do. Later on once I load the users I allow to modify them via the web UI. You are able to add new users or remove the existing ones. And that's where I'm struggling.

It's worth mentioning that I tried to modify the users.value.value.data.Users using setValue() function but when I set it to the simple array then my hardcoded path users.value.value.data.Users from earlier stops working as the newly set users array is now under the path users.value.

When I'm editing users.value.value.data.Users directly this also has no effect on the user interface.

That is probably the problem. React state should always be immutable, so that React can react to changes.

... or do you use the setValue method provided by useAWSGenericRequest ? I'd need to see the code that modifies the object to be sure.

The problem probably lies in the code where you modify the object properties later (you haven't provided that code, but you said in a comment that you are modifying users.value.value.data.Users later).
You should not modify object properties directly. If you do that, React doesn't know about that change, and will not re-render, leaving your component with an outdated state. React state should always be immutable, so that React can react to changes. E.g. use a set... function that comes from some useState hook to change any state (yours is called setValue).
I.e. either replace the whole object with a new object on every change (one useState for the whole object), or extract all the values that you actually need into multiple React states (one useState for each value).
You can still split your code into generic and specific parts. If you have trouble to decide how, I suggest to just try a few ways, e.g. actually write a few of the hooks that you want to avoid (potentially temporarily, to see a clearer picture. You may or may not remove some or all of them later). Then you will probably see clearer what they have in common, and what can be generalized.

Hi,
Thanks a lot for the reply! I tried to modify users.value.value.data.Users both ways: directlly and by using setValue.
When modifying directly like for example
users.value.value.data.Users = users.value.value.data.Users.filter(...);

It had no effect on the user interface(it stayed the same.
The problem with setValue() is that if I do something like:
setValue(users.value.value.data.Users.filter(...))
then my code from the return statement stops working as the paths no longer match.

what does "stops working" mean ? Which return statement do you mean, the return users.map( ... ) ? Very probably the setValue should be the right way to go. I suggest to focus on the problem you have with using setValue, and ask another question about that specifically.
